# Error in installing Cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I am getting this error while installing Cordova.

[image]

I am not behind any proxy, using dongle as internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

The Error you are getting because of bad network connectivity, try to install with faster network, you won't get this problem.

Comment: My network bandwidth is 150 kbs , is this not sufficient ?What is the Size of Cordova File ?

Answer (score 0):

try running the command

```
 npm cache clean
```

and then re-install the package by running

```
npm install -g cordova
```

And make sure you are running cmd prompt with admin rights.

All of the above is not working then downgrade the node version and give a try

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . But i already clean the cache and also set registry . but it's not working .  Cureent version of Nodejs is v4.4.0 x64 i tried to downgrade to the next version also but it's not working .

Comment: My version of npm is 2.14.20 .